# using OpenCV super resolution with large images

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use OpenCV super resolution to increased the resolution of an image by 2. I am following the instruction stated in this document: https://learnopencv.com/super-resolution-in-opencv/

and this document: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d69/tutorial_dnn_superres_benchmark.html

I am using Python 3.8.10 and OpenCV 4.5.1

I am using EDSR_x2.pb model.

I am able to use this model for small images (256 * 256), but when I try to use it with large images (3500 * 3500) I am getting this error:

```
OpenCV(4.5.1) opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:3520: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total(os[i]) > 0 in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20201117::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively'
```

How can I fix this issue?

what is the limitation of this model?

Comment: you could try to perfom the superresolution on subimages and stitch afterwards